# Change JWT payload format with Azure B2C custom policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, zendesk, aad-b2c

I would like to implement JWT SSO for Zendesk with Azure AD B2C custom policies. For some internal reasons, we cannot use SAML.

My problem is Zendesk requires that the return URI respect the format

```
https://yoursubdmain.zendesk.com/access/jwt?jwt={payload}
```

But by default, using Microsoft [samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/LocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml), the return uri is :

```
    https://yoursubdmain.zendesk.com/access/jwt#id_token={payload}
```

I am new user of custom policies, I have no idea how I can change the format of the Redirect URI.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the way AAD B2C return the tokens in the query parameters. You might have to build a proxy to transform the response from AAD B2C and send it to zendesk. Or use SAML.